# Symfony 2 - Per request custom cookie domain

Tags: php, symfony, cookies

My Symfony application currently uses a domain-wise cookie domain, this is for have the user authenticated in all the subdomains, I've set that with the config:

```
framework
    session:
        cookie_domain:  "%site_domain%"
```

where `siite_domain` parameter is the website domain.

Now I've to implement another website section under another domain, I've setup firewall and routes with host restrictions, the problem is that even if the user correctly authenticates the cookie is set to the old domain.

So if the new domain is `integration_domain` and the user logins there the cookie is set to the `site_domain` domain.

I would like to set a cookie on a different domain in the case user logins in the other domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution by myself, basically it's possible to use a custom session save handler to change the domain if the request host matches what I needed, otherwise, leave things untouched:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage;

/**
 * Class to save cookie for session in a different domain for gazzetta integration
 */
class DynamicDomainSessionStorage extends NativeSessionStorage
{
     /**
     * setOptions.
     *
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function setOptions(array $options)
    {

        // Set the cookie domain as the request if we're handling gazzetta session
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) && in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], ['mycustomdomain', 'www.mycustomdomain'])) {
            $options["cookie_domain"] = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        }

        return parent::setOptions($options);
    }
}
```

and this is the configuration change:

```
framework:
      session:
          storage_id: session.storage.dynamicdomain

services:
    session.storage.dynamicdomain:
        class: DynamicDomainSessionStorage
```

I'll leave this open for a couple days if someone finds a better solution

UPDATE: I've just found that if you set the storage_id you can't use the memcached session handler, so this is a semi-fix since it won't let you use a custom storage_handler. Any help is appreciated